I can't connect dBASE to pentaho. I have task to connect dBase database to pentaho to do ETL but i have this error while connect
When I connect to dBASE on petaho, this error keep coming

Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
Driver class 'sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver' could not be found, make sure the 'dBase III, IV or 5' driver (jar file) is installed.
sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver


I have try dowload DBF_JDBC40.jar and HXTT_DBF_JDBC but no use.
Can someone please tell me where the information about dBASE connector or something else.
